# How to debug "The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exist or no valid version could be found"?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

This is what I am trying to do. I have installed Maven. Set the path till bin folder of Maven.

```
C:\Workspace\Eaxample>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mkyong -DartifactId=N
umberGenerator
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'archetype'.
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins: checking for updates from central
[WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retri
eved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Connecti
on timed out: connect
[INFO] Repository 'central' will be blacklisted
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin' does not exi
st or no valid version could be found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 24 14:04:15 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/122M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You forget archetypeArtifactId :

Do this :
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId={project-packaging} 
   -DartifactId={project-name} 
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart 
   -DinteractiveMode=false
```

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/